# Select/dropdowns in new opera (11.60) is small?

Tags: html, select, height, drop-down-menu, opera

Am I the only one wondering why the new update in Opera 11.60 made all standard dropdown menu's look small like on the image beneath?

[image: example]

Is there an "easy" way of fixing this? I guess a fast defined height could solve it, but how would it look in other browsers then.. Is there a universal height of all standard select/dropdowns which could be set?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think I've noticed any such problem. Make sure you don't have extensions, user style sheets or user JS that restyles select elements.

I would recommend that you don't try to change anything in your site's CSS to handle this issue. Adding hacks to handle browser quirks will only make the CSS more brittle in the long run, and this issue is merely cosmetic and may not even be seen by all users.